# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=...) When using MKMap View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I recently encountered a problem with my MKMapView. Whenever I click a button to go to the view with the map in it I get the above error centered around this line.

Updated with full script. error is `let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: (userLocation.location?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 5000, longitudinalMeters: 5000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true) }`

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBAction func mapTypeChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    switch ((sender as AnyObject).selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = .standard
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
    default:
        mapView.mapType = .standard
}
```

`}`

`@IBAction func zoomIn(_ sender: Any) {
        let userLocation = mapView.userLocation
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: (userLocation.location?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 5000, longitudinalMeters: 5000)
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self

    let userLocation = mapView.userLocation
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: (userLocation.location?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 5000, longitudinalMeters: 5000)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */
```

}

There was a formatting problem.

I have no clue why this is as it wasnt happening before. Could anybody help out? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have an error message in console when it happens?

Comment: you are not getting value of "userLocation.location?.coordinate".

Comment: @Larme No. Just Says (11db)

Comment: @Khushbu Ok how can i fix that?

Comment: print this **userLocation.location?.coordinate** to verify it's not nil

Comment: When you use ! You are asking for a crash

Comment: @Sh_Khan Ok, so it says it is nil. It just confuses me as it was working a few hours ago. What do I need to do to fix that.

Comment: By checking why it's nil, and so checking where you are getting it, but without code, that's hard to say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
if let coor = userLocation.location?.coordinate {
   let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center:coor, latitudinalMeters: 5000, longitudinalMeters: 5000)
}
```

it will work if there is a current value for coor , maybe you click it before getting a location so  request for location updates again in else , or initially inside `viewDidLoad`

//

Use this method

```
var once = true
```

//

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
        didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
     if once {
      let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: userLocation.location!.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 5000, longitudinalMeters: 5000)
      mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
      once = false
     }
}
```

of the delegate`MKMapViewDelegate` to get the correct value

Comment: This doesn't center on the user's current location. If you check above I have updated it to show the whole script

Comment: you must have a value for the current location to center , it depends on gps and current location , it happens asynchronously , you may make that centering process inside didUpdateLocation method only once of the delegate , **CLLocationManagerDelegate**

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. I am new to swift so please don't judge me too hard. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: see edit , get rid of once if you want it to always be centered as user moves

Comment: Thanks a lot, man that fixed it. So Just checking. Do I get rid of the entire once var if I want it to update if the location is moving?

Comment: use remove the variable and the if statement if you wanted to